# Issue inputting data in CRM application with webdriver firefox

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, webdriver, crm

I'm using webdriver with python to try to automate a new CRM website we are creating. I'm new to webdriver and i am am having trouble inputting data into fields in the application. I can read from them with no issues but i can't seem to input data into them. To read data in the field I simply have

```
   Mobile_Num= driver.find_element_by_id("mobilephone").text
```

which works fine. But when i try send_keys with the same selector it doesn't work. I have tired

```
Mobile_Num.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
Mobile_Num.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
Mobile_Num.click()
Mobile_Num.send_keys("11111")

<td id="mobilephone_c" class="ms-crm-ReadField-Normal ms-crm-FieldLabel-LeftAlign" title="Type the mobile phone number for the contact.">
<td id="mobilephone_d" class="ms-crm-Field-Data-Print" data-height="24">
<div id="mobilephone" class="ms-crm-ltrcontrol ms-crm-Inline-Chrome nvarchar" tabindex="1110" data-layout="0" data-fdeid="PrimaryEntity" data-formid="1fed44d1-ae68-4a41-bd2b-f13acac4acfa" data-attributename="mobilephone" data-initialized="true" aria-describedby="mobilephone_c" title="This is the Value of field" haserror="false">
<div class="ms-crm-Inline-Value" style="display: block;">
<span>
<a class="ms-crm-gridurl ms-crm-Phone" href="#" title="Prefix the number with "+<country code><area code>" and install Skype to make calls from Microsoft Dynamics CRM.">This is the Value of field</a>
<div class="ms-crm-Inline-GradientMask"></div>
</span>
</div>
<span class="ms-crm-Inline-LockIcon" style="display: none;">
<div class="ms-crm-Inline-Edit" style="display: none;">
<span class="ms-crm-Inline-WarningIcon" title="" style="display: none;">
</div>
</td>
```

Webdriver does not show any errors after the test but if the data is checked it hasn't be updated correctly. I am using the firefox driver.
I have googled this problem quite a bit but with little success.  Can anyone point me in the right direction here i.e. do i need javascript to fire the events and then use webdriver to input the text? I am sill of the assumption that webdriver should be able to do all this! Thanks

Comment: When you are sending keys `Mobile_Num` is `Mobile_Num=driver.find_element_by_id("mobilephone")` ?

Comment: SendKeys works only with a input text box. In your case, it looks like a div. Which element you are trying to set the value.

Comment: The value looks to be stored in an array of elements, but the one i want to update is the link text. So driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='mobilephone']/div/span/a").send_keys("Value"). What do you use instead of send_keys for these types of elements?

Comment: Ok,so i got it to work eventually.I need to click the element first.                                                              `Mobile_Num = driver.find_element_by_id("mobilephone").click()` then I had to use send_keys on the other input element i had missed from my html code above.                                  `Mobile_Num1 = driver.find_element_by_id("mobilephone_i")`
`Mobile_Num1.send_keys("My Number")`.                               I had to click the first element to make the second element active. Hope this helps